# Creating email link with dynamically generated body with html5 & javascript

Tags: javascript, html, email, mailto

Am trying to create a link to create an email to send information to the user, the body of which needs to be filled with data generated by a javascript function, and hope that someone can help.

Idealy, if I could substitute the 'body_blurb' below, with a string returned from a javascript function called at the time of clicking that'd be perfect.

```
<A HREF="mailto:you@yourdomain.com?subject=Data&body=body_blurb">e-mail data</a>
```

Appreciate your time

Comment: You could do that relatively easily, but what event is binding body_blurb to that anchor? Are the users clicking on something prior to the mail anchor?

Comment: Do you realize that `mailto:` often doesn't work, particularly when users are using a web-based email service like Yahoo, GMail, Hotmail, etc... and thus there is no local email client to field the mailto: and act on it?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I just assigned an id to the link here, but you could create something more generic if you wanted. Once you have an onclick handler created you can access the url with `href`. Set this to whatever you want.

http://jsfiddle.net/f3ZZL/1

```
var link = document.getElementById('email');
link.onclick = function() {
    this.href = "mailto:you@yourdomain.com?subject=Data&body=";
    this.href += getBody();
};

function getBody() {
    return 'HelloWorld';
}
```

Comment: Perfect - exactly what I was after. By way of further explanation, I'm creating a simple engineering calculation number cruncher to be accssed via mobile browsers. The user would enter their variables, crunch the numbers and get an output. I'd like to be able to give them the option of sending themselves the data set of inputs & outputs.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the no-spam method

```js
var link = document.getElementById('email');

link.onclick = function() {
    var name = "you";
    var domain = "yourdomain.com";
    var linker = "mailto:" + name + '@' + domain + "?subject=Data&body=";
    linker += getBody();
    link.setAttribute("href", linker);
};

function getBody() {
    return 'HelloWorld';
}
```

[On Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Lo3m8gkp/)

Answer (score 0):

You don't actually need to set the `href` value. What you're really trying to do is send the browser to a `mailto:` URL: the `href` is just a means to that end.

Leave the `href` blank and make the link have an `onClick` handler. In the `onClick`, feed the browser the `mailto:` URL (after you build it using your variable). Presto, done.

Comment: Hmmm, so you could use `location.href = mailto: ...`?