# Link to prefilled email body with form

Tags: html, email

I would like to create a link that opens your default email client (e.g. Gmail on your iPhone) with the following filled out:

- **TO:** example@gmail.com
- **SUBJECT:** Your Order
- **BODY:** [A form as opposed to
  a text]

I know how to do the above if the Body is just a text (see below) but not if it is e.g. a HTML form.

Code if it is just a body text:

```
<a href="mailto:email@gmail.com?subject=Your%20Order&body=">Click here to send pre-filled email</a>
```

Thanks for help!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Creating email link with dynamically generated body with html5 & javascript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9014470/creating-email-link-with-dynamically-generated-body-with-html5-javascript)

Answer (score 0):

Duplicated of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9014470/creating-email-link-with-dynamically-generated-body-with-html5-javascript)

heres the code:

```
var link = document.getElementById('email');
link.onclick = function() {
    this.href = "mailto:you@yourdomain.com?subject=Data&body=";
    this.href += getBody();
};

function getBody() {
    return 'HelloWorld';
}
```